# Manifest and GetVersionEx

Tags: delphi, windows-10, manifest, delphi-xe4

I am currently experimenting with adding an `example.manifest` file next to my `example.exe` program, so `GetVersionEx()` returns correct information.

However - it seems to not have made any difference at all - I still only get 6.2.

Here is my manifest file that I intend to use for all my 32/64 bit Windows executables:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
        type="win32"
        name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
        version="6.0.0.0"
        publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
        language="*"
        processorArchitecture="*"
      />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="asInvoker"
          uiAccess="false"
        />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <!-- Windows 10 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
      <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
      <!-- Windows Vista -->
      <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/>
      <!-- Windows 7 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
      <!-- Windows 8 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
    </application>
  </compatibility>
</assembly>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file should be named `example.exe.manifest` rather than `example.manifest`.

But even then, IIRC, the `supportedOS` settings are ignored for an external manifest. So you will have to embed the manifest as a resource instead. This is a much more robust approach in any case.

Comment: Thank you - I will try find a tool that allows editing .res file. So far two crashed opening my .res file. But I will try add manifest directly into .res file - thank you. I will accept as answer soon!

Comment: Don't try to edit .res files. You need to take control of building the res file. Create a .rc file and pass it to a resource compiler. This should all be part of your automated build process.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to @David's answer.

There is no need for external tools and editing res files. Newer Delphi versions (XE4 included) have setting in Project Options that allows including custom external manifest file and Delphi will take care of building and including it into final executable.

`Project Options -> Application -> Runtime Themes` - select `Use custom manifest` and browse for your manifest file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The way I ended up solving this was using a resource tool (e.g. Resource Tuner can do it) to add the manifest file to the .res file.

- I have turned off all IDE stuff for themes, custom manifest, icons etc.
- I do not include xpman in uses
- I include my .res file containing manifest and icons inside main .dpr unit

It works since both themes and getversionex now returns correct results.

...

For build automation - my build script generated by another script pulls in the correct .res file depending on product/edition being built.